# Como dar formato de un archivo txt, mostrarlo en un html el contenido y con paginacion, ayuda por favor!

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hola amigos buenas tardes,

He creado un proyecto que me solictaron para un trabajo que me postulé y me pidieron que hiciera que en un html se visualice el contenido de un archivo de .txt ya tengo algo avanzado de codigo que encontré, ya funciona y ya se ve desde en el mismo html(jsp), aquí el problema es que no se como  hacerlo de manera de paginacion, es decir que no me arroje todo el contenido sino de 20 en 20 por medio de la barra, algo parecido como cuando buscamos algo en google, ya que los registro son mas de 40,000 y que se muestre como tipo tablas dichos registros.

Este es el codigo que ya funciona y esta en javascript:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload=function(){

function leerArchivo(e) {
      var archivo = e.target.files[0];
      if (!archivo) {
        return;
      }
      var lector = new FileReader();
      lector.onload = function(e) {
        var contenido = e.target.result;
        mostrarContenido(contenido);
      };
      lector.readAsText(archivo);
    }

    function mostrarContenido(contenido) {
      var elemento = document.getElementById('contenido-archivo');
      elemento.innerHTML = contenido;
    }

    document.getElementById('file-input')
      .addEventListener('change', leerArchivo, false);

}
</script>


<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hola mundo</h1>
<input type="file" id="file-input" />
<h3>Contenido del archivo:</h3>
<pre id="contenido-archivo"></pre>

</body>
</html>
```

Asi es como se ve de resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero y que mas o menos me pueda dar a entender y me ayuden con esto por favor, quedo al pendiente si hay algo que no se entienda, saludos y buena vibra.

Comment: Te puedo recomendar https://datatables.net/

Comment: Hola, nunca he usado esa forma de hacerlo, podrias brindarme algun ejemplo para poder guiarme por favor? Saludos.